# How to sync datawarehouse datamodel with transactional database with dynamic datamodel?

Tags: database, synchronization, data-warehouse, data-migration, datamodel

Imagine I have a transactional database with a datamodel that can change. For example, a column is added or editted. I also have a datawarehouse that needs to be in sync with this database.

So if I change the datamodel from the database, the datawarehouse datamodel should update also and *not* the other way around.

Question: What are the most viable options to let the datawarehouse have the same columns as the database?

Suggestions that came to my mind:

-Generating an import script of the database datamodel so the datawarehouse can import it.
-Changing import script of the datawarehouse by hand. (not prefered)

Feel free to suggest any other options! (please explain why)

Comment: do you mean importing to the staging area in your data warehouse? if yes then is dropping/re-creating the table an option or are you using incremental load in your ETL?

Comment: What would be good options when using incremental load in the ETL process and why?